# "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied" in Android Internal Cache Dir

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am trying to take a picture and save it to the application's internal cache as it is going to be deleted as soon as it is uploaded. I am using the following code to create the file:

```
public static File createInternalCacheImageFile(Context context, String imageFileName) throws IOException {
        return File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                context.getString(R.string.image_extension),
                context.getCacheDir()
        );
    }
```

Checking with a file manager with root permissions shows that the file is created fine. I then use the following code to launch the camera intent, which would normally save the image to the file I created:

```
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

The camera activity is shown and after accepting the picture, the result of the activity is 0. When looking at the `logcat` the following is shown:

```
07-21 13:19:51.093  12889-12889/? E/CAM_StateSavePic﹕ exception while saving result to URI: Optional.of(file:///data/data/org.serengetitracker.androidapp/cache/image_random_205854910-2018234447.jpg)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
            at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:253)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:199)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:916)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:686)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:662)
            at com.android.camera.captureintent.state.StateSavingPicture.onEnter(StateSavingPicture.java:84)
            at com.android.camera.captureintent.stateful.StateMachineImpl.jumpToState(StateMachineImpl.java:62)
            at com.android.camera.captureintent.stateful.StateMachineImpl.processEvent(StateMachineImpl.java:110)
            at com.android.camera.captureintent.state.StateOpeningCamera$9.onClick(StateOpeningCamera.java:307)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

**Why am I not allowed to write an image to the application's internal cache directory?**

Note: I do have the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in my application, although this shouldn't matter as I'm not dealing with the external storage.

Comment: instead of creating image in cache try to create in your `data/data/org.serengetitracker.androidapp/images`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The camera activity runs in a different app, which does not have access to your app's internal cache directory. You must use an external directory or let the camera app choose the directory itself - and then query that path (another topic) to be able to copy it to your cache directory.

Answer (score 2):

This *is* possible without the `CAMERA` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

You can create a temporary in your app's cache directory, and give other apps access to it. That makes the file writeable by the camera app:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("photo", ".jpg", context.getCacheDir());
tempFile.setWritable(true, false);
```

Now you just need to pass this file as the output file for the camera intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mTempFile));  // pass temp file
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

Note: the file Uri won't be passed to you in the Activity result, you'll have to keep a reference to the tempFile and retrieve it from there.

Comment: In Android 6.0.1 - permission denied

Answer (score 1):

from following link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir() getCacheDir()

```
Returns the absolute path to the application specific cache directory on the filesystem
```

Your application has complete access to this path, but here you are passing URI which lies in your cache directory through intent to Camera application and it is trying to access the cacheDir of your application to store image it has captured but it cannot access it.

One solution would be to use a folder on external directory.